# UIImage returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, null

I'll be creating an `UIImage` but if I debug the method it returns `nil`.
I hope someone know what I have to do.

**My code:**

returns nil:

```
UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
```

**Whole block of code:**

```
UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

**Update:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        toolbar.hidden = NO;

        UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
        NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];

    }

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {

        toolbar.hidden = NO;

        UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
        NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
    }

    if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {

        toolbar.hidden = NO;

        UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
        NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
        [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
    }

    else{

        toolbar.hidden = NO;

    }

    imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: where do you set the imageView's image?

Comment: What do you mean with "set the imageView's image" ?

Comment: No, imgView (is the image View) is not nil.

Comment: can you show the code where you are setting the imgView image. Please note that you can have imgView which is not nil, but if you haven't attached a image to it, its image property(imgView.image) will be nil.

Comment: @Priyatham51 The image can be chosen from the gallery or can be taken by the camera. The code is in the question (imagePickerController)

Comment: try moving this line 
imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]; 
 to the beginning of the method.

Comment: Make sure that `info` is not nil and that `[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]` is not nil. If that is the first place that you are setting `imgView.image`, then it will be nil the first time this method is called, until you get to the second to last line.

Comment: Yes, this way is working. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to use the imgView.image property even before you set it.

imageView.image is being set with this line

```
imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
```

Move that line to beginning of the method. like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

 imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;

    UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
    NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you are setting `imgView.image` to a value is near the end of `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`. Therefore, the first time this method is called, `imgView.image` is going to be `nil` until it is set at the end with:

```
imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, gonna skip reading your code and just post what works for me.

```
- (UIImage *) getImage{

    NSString *pathAndFileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"somefile.png"  ofType:nil];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pathAndFileName])
    {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"somefile.png"];
    }
    else{
        NSString *t = [self pathToImageInCache:@"somefile.png"];

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:t]){
            NSLog(@"fiel exists");
            return [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:t];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"fiel does not exists");
        }
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSString *) pathToImageInCache: (NSString *) imageName{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@""];

    NSString *URLImg = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    return URLImg;
}
```