# UIImage returns nil (xcode5)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, null

My UIImage is nil if I try to test this block of code:

```
- (IBAction)sliderBrightness:(id)sender {

    UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;

    GPUImageBrightnessFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageBrightnessFilter alloc] init];
    GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];

    [stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
    [stillImageFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [stillImageSource processImage];

    UIImage *currentFilteredVideoFrame = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
    [self->imgView setImage:currentFilteredVideoFrame];
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;

    UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
    NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];

}

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;

    UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
    NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
}

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;

    UIImage *image1 = imgView.image;
    NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
}

else{

    toolbar.hidden = NO;

}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Debugger (inputImage is nil):

[image]

I hope someone can help me. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

*I'm using xcode 5.1.1 (iOS Simulator: iPhone 4-inch; 64-Bit; iOS7.1)*

Comment: How and when do you set `imgView.image`?

Comment: I set imgView.image in a method after this IBAction (imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];)

Comment: *Which* image is nil? `inputImage` or `currentFilteredVideoFrame`?

Comment: If you set imgView.image AFTER this runs, as you just said, then what would its value be while this is running?

Comment: @Logan Ok, now i set the image before it runs but it's still not working.

Comment: @Caleb The `inputImage` is nil.

Comment: This appears to be the same question, by the same user, as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391956/uiimage-returns-nil

Comment: Also, why are you using `self→imgView` instead of `self.imgView` or `[self imgView`]?

Answer (score 1):

If (as you say in comments) the problem is that `inputImage` is nil, the problem is external to the code you've posted. Either `imgView` is itself nil, or it points to a `UIImageView` instance that hasn't yet had its image set. Put a breakpoint on the line:

```
UIImage *inputImage = imgView.image;
```

and inspect `imgView` to determine which of those possibilities is the problem.

Comment: The imgView isn't nil and the image in the imgView is seted (selected from the gallery). I posted an image in my question. Maybe it helps to solve the question?

Comment: The debugger stops before the current line is executed. You need to step over the line where the debugger is stopped in order for the assignment to `inputImage` to happen.

Comment: Ok, now inputImage is not nil but it's still crashing. And what you should know is that the IBAction is a UISlider which should change the brightness.